# Getting the date and sending it through mysqli insert?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically I've got a contact us form, and I would like to submit the date as well, when the submit button is pressed. Basically you fill out the boxes, submit, and the date goes through with it. I am just not sure exactly how to do it...

I've got the form in a .php in another page, but the action leads to the current page.

The date needs to be: year-mm-dd

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
$date = //I need the date here so it can go through the insert propperly;


if ($_POST['submit']){

    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO contactusresults (`id`, `date`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `question`) VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$name', '$email' , '$phone', '$question')") or die(mysql_error());


    header('Location: ../pages/index.php'); 
    //change to submit page 
}else{
    header('Location: ../pages/index.php');
}


?>
```

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['date']))

Comment: just use `CURDATE()`.

Comment: Where exactly do I put "NOW()"

Comment: edited, not `NOW()` but `CURDATE()`. you're also open to an sql injection

Comment: @AustinM-S I see you accepted the other answer; that's fine, I'm ok with that (from what I posted). However and I need to note that it will be much easier to query later on (on SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) using MySQL's built-in date/datetime features/functions. The choice is yours, but take it from experience. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php date function.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // If your mysql column is datetime
$date = date("Y-m-d"); // If your mysql column is just date
```

Use NOW() in sql

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO contactusresults (`id`, `date`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `question`) 
VALUES (NULL, NOW(), '$name', '$email' , '$phone', '$question')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `NOW()` returns `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` and not the intended `YYYY-mm-dd`

Answer (score 2):

> *"The date needs to be: year-mm-dd"*

Use MySQL's `CURDATE()` function, as it returns YYYY-mm-dd.

```
VALUES (NULL, CURDATE(), '$name', ...
```

and be sure to set your date column to a DATE type. If it's presently `VARCHAR` then it won't work.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html

You should also add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

**Note:** `mysql_error()` that needs to read as `mysqli_error($connect)`. The MySQL_ and MySQLi_ APIs do not intermix.

Your connection method is unknown, so you need to use the same one that you used for your query, being the MySQLi_ API.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

If it's MySQL_ or PDO, then those will not work with your query. Different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

You should also check for errors.

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli` with a **prepared statement**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Foonotes:**

> *"I've got the form in a .php in another page, but the action leads to the current page."*

That is unclear. The action needs to lead to your query code. "The current page" (to me) means either `action="html_form.php"` or `action=""`.

Therefore it needs to be changed to the one you're using to query with.

You also should check against empty fields using `empty()`.

Another thing. I noticed you are using NULL for your `id` column. Make sure that it does accept NULL values, otherwise your query will fail. If that should be the case, and that your `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT, then use `''` as per the following for the `id` column.

```
VALUES ('', CURDATE(), '$name', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the selected answer:

On your MySQL table you can set the column for the date value to save the `timestamp` of the insert, which will include the date as specified, and can be called using the `DATE_FORMAT` function. This method would completely negate the need to manually set and save the date value upon insert.

Table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `contactusresults` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(256),
    `email` VARCHAR(256),
    `phone` VARCHAR(256),
    `question` VARCHAR(256),
    `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
```

Table Insert:

```
 mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO contactusresults (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `question`) VALUES ( '$name', '$email' , '$phone', '$question')") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

To extract the date from the table data:

```
$var = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `name`,DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%d-%m') as `date` FROM contactusresults WHERE id = 1");
```

NOTES:

- Your MySQLi_error needs to be `mysqli_` and needs to contain the connection variable.
- Any `NULL` values upon insert, such as the `id` can be ignored
- Only one timestamp column can be set in a table.